# How can we create an AsymmetricSecurityKey?

Tags: c#

How we can create AsymmetricSecurityKey in c#. Actually we are creating signing credentials with AsymetricSecurityKey  here is our code:

```
// Define const Key this should be private secret key  stored in some safe place
string key = "401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429090fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1";

// Create Security key  using private key above:
// not that latest version of JWT using Microsoft namespace instead of System
var securityKey = new AsymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));

// Also note that securityKey length should be >256b
// so you have to make sure that your private key has a proper length
//
var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials
                  (securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
```

Comment: In asymmetric I don't think one can provide private/public key, it can only be generated.

Comment: this might help https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L172

Comment: @FaizanRabbani, can you please provide me any example code for generate AsymmetricSecurityKey in C#?

Comment: `AsymmetricSecurityKey` is abstract class, you need to create specific implementation. For example if you are using RSA: `var securityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(...)`

Answer (score 5):

You can generate public/private keys using:

```
public void GenerateRsaCryptoServiceProviderKey()
{
        var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
        SecurityKey key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaProvider);      
}
```

You should use `RsaSha256` below:

```
var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials
                  (key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);
```

Comment: Actually i need to create SigningCredentials object from AsymmetricSecurityKey

Comment: i.e var credentials = new SigningCredentials(asymmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

Answer (score 1):

Signing credentials with a `AsymmetricSecurityKey` in C# using a RSA private key:

```
// RSA Private Key Base64
var privateKey = @"...";

var privateKeyBuffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[privateKey.Length]);
Convert.TryFromBase64String(privateKey, privateKeyBuffer, out _);

// abstract class RSA : AsymmetricAlgorithm in namespace System.Security.Cryptography
var rsaPrivateKey = RSA.Create();
rsaPrivateKey.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer, out _);

// class RsaSecurityKey : AsymmetricSecurityKey in namespace Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaPrivateKey);
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(rsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);
```

This is a possible solution on how to create `AsymmetricSecurityKey` object and a `SigningCredentials` object when we have a RSA private key (asymmetric key) in string format.

When you want to use asymmetric keys that are generated outside your application, you may need this additional steps to import an externally generated key.

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over those provided by prior answers? Can you [edit] your answer to explain what you're doing differently, and what the benefits (or, perhaps, tradeoffs) of your approach are?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically looking for an `AsymmetricSecurityKey`?

I noticed that you are referencing the HM256 algorithm. That leads me to believe that you are looking for a `SymmetricSecurityKey`. Also, your approach seems very specific to using the HMAC alg.

To generate a `SymmetricSecurityKey`, you can try something like the following code:

```
// Define const Key this should be private secret key  stored in some safe place
string key = "401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429090fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1";

// Create Security key  using private key above:
// not that latest version of JWT using Microsoft namespace instead of System
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));

// Also note that securityKey length should be >256b
// so you have to make sure that your private key has a proper length
//
var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
```

If you would like the a solution for using an RS256 alg (which will use a cert in pfx format), you can comment and I will do my best to give you an example of that too.

Answer (score 0):

This creates security key from an RSA public key in F#.

```
    let pem = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnzyis1ZjfNB0bBgKFMSvvkTtwlvBsaJq7S5wA+kzeVOVpVWwkWdVha4s38XM/pa/yr47av7+z3VTmvDRyAHcaT92whREFpLv9cj5lTeJSibyr/Mrm/YtjCZVWgaOYIhwrXwKLqPr/11inWsAkfIytvHWTxZYEcXLgAXFuUuaS3uF9gEiNQwzGTU1v0FqkqTBr4B8nW3HCN47XUu0t8Y0e+lf4s4OxQawWD79J9/5d3Ry0vbV3Am1FtGJiJvOwRsIfVChDpYStTcHTCMqtvWbV6L11BWkpzGXSW4Hv43qa+GSYOD2QU68Mb59oSk2OB+BtOLpJofmbGEGgvmwyCI9MwIDAQAB"
        
    let getPublicKey (pem: string) =
            let publicKey = ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Convert.FromBase64String(pem))
            let rsa = RSA.Create()
            let mutable read = 0
            rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKey, &read)
            new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)

    getPublicKey pem
```